# "mmal: No data received from sensor" error

Tags: raspicam, mmal

I have some problems with the raspicam,can you help me Please?

In fact, It was working without problems since the last month but, yesterday, it starts to display this error when I ran raspistill -o:

> mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including
>   the Sunny one on the camera board

I looked through the different forums and topics, but all the proposed solutions were useless:

I updated the system

tried on 2 raspberry cards and cameras (and checked and changed the cables)

split the memory: 512

overclocked the CPU to medium

On the way, when I run the raspistill command, the raspicam still showing the red light. Also, the card detects the camera and the output of "vcgencmd get_camera" is:

> supported=1 detected=1

the output of "raspistill -v" is :

> raspistill Camera App v1.3.8
>
> Width 2592, Height 1944, quality 85, filename iii.jpg
>
> Time delay 5000, Raw no
>
> Thumbnail enabled Yes, width 64, height 48, quality 35
>
> Link to latest frame enabled  no
>
> Full resolution preview No
>
> Capture method : Single capture
>
> Preview Yes, Full screen Yes
>
> Preview window 0,0,1024,768
>
> Opacity 255
>
> Sharpness 0, Contrast 0, Brightness 50
>
> Saturation 0, ISO 0, Video Stabilisation No, Exposure compensation 0
>
> Exposure Mode 'auto', AWB Mode 'auto', Image Effect 'none'
>
> Metering Mode 'average', Colour Effect Enabled No with U = 128, V =
>   128
>
> Rotation 0, hflip No, vflip No
>
> ROI x 0.000000, y 0.000000, w 1.000000 h 1.000000
>
> Camera component done
>
> Encoder component done
>
> Starting component connection stage
>
> Connecting camera preview port to video render.
>
> Connecting camera stills port to encoder input port
>
> Opening output file iii.jpg
>
> Enabling encoder output port
>
> Starting capture 0
>
> mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including
>   the Sunny one on the camera board

I have a raspberry 2 Model B, this is the CPUinfo content:

> processor : 0
>
> model name : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
>
> BogoMIPS : 57.60
>
> Features : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva
>   idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
>
> CPU implementer : 0x41
>
> CPU architecture: 7
>
> CPU variant : 0x0
>
> CPU part : 0xc07
>
> CPU revision : 5
>
> processor : 1
>
> model name : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
>
> BogoMIPS : 57.60
>
> Features : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva
>   idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
>
> CPU implementer : 0x41
>
> CPU architecture: 7
>
> CPU variant : 0x0
>
> CPU part : 0xc07
>
> CPU revision : 5
>
> processor : 2
>
> model name : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
>
> BogoMIPS : 57.60
>
> Features : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva
>   idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
>
> CPU implementer : 0x41
>
> CPU architecture: 7
>
> CPU variant : 0x0
>
> CPU part : 0xc07
>
> CPU revision : 5
>
> processor : 3
>
> model name : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
>
> BogoMIPS : 57.60
>
> Features : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva
>   idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
>
> CPU implementer : 0x41
>
> CPU architecture: 7
>
> CPU variant : 0x0
>
> CPU part : 0xc07
>
> CPU revision : 5
>
> Hardware : BCM2709
>
> Revision : a21041
>
> Serial : 0000000073c3e333

Can you help me please? Its very important

Answer (score -1):

I have seen a lot of discussion on this error but no real root causes identified.

This amazon reviewer seems to believe it has to do with a WIFI card.

http://www.amazon.com/review/R24IH1QU5Y266L/ref=cm_cr_rdp_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B012ETE75I

Comment: However they do not go on to provide any supporting evidence (for that product there was three comments in the approximately six months that it had been on that site and the other two were for positive outcomes) so I do  not think we can generalise from that specific case...